# c#: showing the selection of text in a textbox while another form is focused

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm implementing a find and replace dialog; There is a main Windows From which has a textbox and another Windows Form (the find and replace dialog); Till now everything is OK except when I click my find button it does find and select the text in the textbox but to see the selection I have to activate(focus) on the parent window.

How can I show the selection in the parent window while not loosing the focus of child window?

while the focus is on the child dialog:
[image]

After setting the focus on the parent window:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the textbox HideSelection property to false.

You can see it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.